# Estimation of an Entropic Path Integral

Tags: entropy, path-integral

I'm trying to reproduce some results from a paper (http://www.alexwg.org/publications/PhysRevLett_110-168702.pdf for reference) and basically I need a way of estimating a particular path integral (shown below). We have equations of motion to evolve individual paths and the method given in the SI seems to be that you sample a number of paths in order to estimate the path probability density. This is from the supplementary information:

[image]

So $\vec{x_i}(t)$ is a path that is discretized into timesteps (in the example I'm doing 400 timesteps with an x-component and a y-component at each timestep). Now I don't know very much about kernel density estimation, but this strikes me as a difficult problem as the path space in my example is 800 dimensional, and unsurprisingly if I just feed it into MATLAB's mvksdensity function (to estimate just the path probability density) it just returns a lot of zeros. Is there something about the fact that you are trying to estimate not the actual probability density but $\log(\frac{\Omega_i}{\sum \Omega_{i'}})$ where $\Omega_i = \frac{1}{M p_i}$ (M is number of sample paths) that makes it easier? If so how do you go about doing this?

Alternatively if anyone has any ideas for different methods I could use to estimate that path integral that would be great as well!

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Answer (score 1):

As I interpret kernel density should be fitted for x-y (2-dimensional space),instead of an 800-dimensional space. The point is to collect information about phase-space volume visited by each random microstate (aka simulated but not committed trajectory).